# is Google ManagedConfiguration API is also supported on android/ios?

Tags: google-chrome, google-api, google-chrome-app

i have added this line in my code which fetched the configuration for my application ,
navigator.managed.getManagedConfiguration(['Config'])

However , when i am trying to access from my chrome android browser site is getting creashed.

is it even supported on android or only for dekstops.

wiki on ManagedConfiguration :
https://wicg.github.io/WebApiDevice/managed_config/

i treid running my website on dekstops like mac , windows it was working there.

POC : navigate to https://google.com on android , open console and type :

navigator.managed.getManagedConfiguration(['CONFIG_NAME'])

you will see aw,snap error.

Comment: After lots of research Google's managedConfiguration API was deprecated after chrome version 91 in Android.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research Google's managedConfiguration API was deprecated after chrome version 91 in Android.